# Pagination in Drop Down (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, pagination, dropdown

Is there any way to use drop-down with pagination feature in flutter?. Basically, I need to update drop-down items on the API changes(with limit and offset).

Comment: Generally, pagination does not use in dropDown when you need to filter it's contained more complex, it would be good to retrieve all data at first.

Comment: but my API uses pagination, otherwise, it will take a long time to execute.

Comment: For dropdown, it would be good practice to always use a quick responsive API. I hope there is someone, will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If regardless you get the solution to achieve let's say, it's **not** a good practice to use pagination for something like a dropdown. If the response is something that gives a lot of data, it's not a great **User Experience** to make them scroll down to find anyways.

One approach you can take is to take the user to another screen/modal dialog/modal bottom sheet and give them the option to **Search** or maybe show the listing there with some filters/search.

Comment: Thank you Sahil for the suggestion, I am using the modal sheet for now.